Error when consolidating Python Web Tool in ArcGIS Pro 3.3. Not all the reference code is consolidated
In version ArcGIS Pro 2.9,3.0 and 3.1 the following structure of a web tool worked as intended when it was staged, in order to be published in ArcGIS Enterprise:
Updm2018
└── TestService.atbx
├  __init__.py
├  MyTestService.py
├  foo.py
└──bar
    ├ __init__.py
    ├ real_bar.py
    ├ file_required_by_baz.json
    └─ baz.py

The definition was staged using the StageService function and the .sd file will include the required files.
In the version 3.3 it does not behave as it used to do it, now the referenced modules in subfolders are not consolidated.
Note: I also tried using the Save As Offline Service Definition tool:

It is worth to mention that the file MyTestService.py include the imports:
…
import foo
from bar import realbar
from bar import baz
…

Execution of the tool StageService in ArcGIS Pro 3.3.1 generates an .sd file with the following structure (.sd file is just a zip file):
│   manifest.xml
│   serviceconfiguration.json
│   tilingservice.xml
│
├───cd
│   └───updm2018
│           foo.py
│           MyTestService.py
│           TestService.atbx
│
├───esriinfo
│   │   iteminfo.xml
│   │
│   └───metadata
│           metadata.xml
│
└───p30
        MyTestService.msd
        MyTestService.rltx
        MyTestService.tbx

There are missing files required by the tool to properly run:
real_bar.py
file_required_by_baz.json
baz.py

Following the indications of the documentation , it should be possible to do it. As a matter of fact it has been working with out any issue, until this version.
Am I missing some new configuration in the staging process?

2 things: 1) If this has worked in a prior version and has stopped working in a newer version without any code changes: that sounds like a bug you should submit to support. 2) A file you said is not consolidated, file_required_by_baz.json, where is the reference? I could be wrong, but I thought only files referenced from the main script were consolidated. Not a file referenced from a consolidated file (however I could be wrong in this point)

@KHibma the file is referenced by baz.py. I can confirm you that files referenced by other consolidated files were consolidated too in version 3.0 and 3.1 of ArcGIS Pro.

In root level, I created a file called modules_importer.py:
Updm2018
└── TestService.atbx
├  __init__.py
├  MyTestService.py
├  modules_importer.py
├  foo.py
└──bar
    ├ __init__.py
    ├ real_bar.py
    ├ file_required_by_baz.json
    └─ baz.py

Inside the file I put the following code:
import arcpy
import sys
from os.path import exists


def set_path():
    bar_module = r".\bar"
        
    if exists(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace + '\\..\\cd\\'):
        sys.path.append(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace + '\\..\\cd\\')
 

Modified the imports of the file MyTestService.py:
...
import arcpy
import foo

arcpy.AddMessage("Loading own modules")
import modules_importer
modules_importer.set_path()
arcpy.AddMessage("AfterLoading own modules")

import bar.real_bar as real_bar
import bar.baz as baz
....


When the stage definition is created, is very important  to select the Copy all data option (in ArcGIS Pro):


or its equivalent in python: setting True the property copyDataToServer in the GeoprocessingSharingDraft class.
when all this is set, the creation of the .sd file will consolidate, and the file structure will be:
│   manifest.xml
│   serviceconfiguration.json
│   tilingservice.xml
│
├───cd
│   ├───updm2018
│   │        foo.py
│   │       MyTestService.py
│   │       TestService.atbx
│   └───bar
│           real_bar.py
│           file_required_by_baz.json
│            baz.py
│
├───esriinfo
│   │   iteminfo.xml
│   │
│   └───metadata
│           metadata.xml
│
└───p30
        MyTestService.msd
        MyTestService.rltx
        MyTestService.tbx

and the file modules_importer.py will be consolidated as:
# Esri start of added imports
import sys, os, arcpy
# Esri end of added imports

# Esri start of added variables
g_ESRI_variable_1 = os.path.join(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace,'..\\cd\\bar')
# Esri end of added variables

import arcpy
import sys
from os.path import exists

def set_path():    
    bar_module = g_ESRI_variable_1
    # pythonModules = r".\\" # this line make a recursive call to the current folder
    arcpy.AddMessage("Call set_path")
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace + '\\..\\cd\\')
    if exists(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace + '\\..\\cd\\'):
        sys.path.append(arcpy.env.packageWorkspace + '\\..\\cd\\')

Having this folder structure and with the cd folder added to the PATH, the imports to modules are resolved properly.

I chatted with the Esri Geoprocessing Services Team -- they confirmed this is a bug and have entered a ticket into their system. I can't make any promises on their behalf, but they've set a target to fix in ArcGIS Pro 3.4
